# Copy the Excel RANK formula without changing the end reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking-functions

Suppose I have a simple spreadsheet with 3 rows of data that I want to rank in separate columns. The example I will use is simple, but my actual dataset is 12k + rows. In this simple example, I want to use the RANK formula from Excel to do this. To rank the values in column `Police`, I'll use the formula `=RANK(B2, B2:B11, 1)`, with B2:B11 being the range.

[image]

As I mentioned, my actual dataset has thousands of rows and many more columns to compare. Even in this example, I want a simple way to copy the formula to all of the other `_RANK` column cells. If I simply copy the cell to the other cells, +1 gets added to the cell value. This is what I want to happen, EXCEPT for the ending cell of the range.

[image]

As you can see above, this is incorrect. The formula gets set to `=RANK(B11,B11:B20,1)` for cell `E11`, when what I want is `=RANK(B11,B11:B11,1)`. How can I easily copy this formula across multiple cells so that it is has the correct formula?

Comment: The `B11:B11` in `=RANK(B11,B11:B11,1)` doesn't make a lot of sense. What exactly do you want the range to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing $ before the cell references makes it static. Try changing your formula to Rank(B11, B$2:B$20,1). Coping this formula will only change those references which are not proceeded with $.